# change value of a timestamp format into other timestamp format?

Tags: java, timestamp

Hi can anyone tell me how can i change a given timestamp format into other timestamp format
like

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Calendar d1 = Calendar.getInstance();
d1.setTime(formatter.parse("2012-03-08 17:32:56"));
```

to

```
"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

format the date with new date format **dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss**

```
   DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   Date oldFormatedDate = formatter.parse("2012-03-08 17:32:56");
   System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").
   format(oldFormatedDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Continue with [`DateFormat#format(Date)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29):

```
SimpleDateFormatter newFormat = new SimpleDateFormatter("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String newFormattedDate = newFormat.format(d1);
```